# C# Get information from jscript inside webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, web-scraping

Using C#, I am trying to get back "P250 | Metallic DDPAT (Factory New)" from this (Inside the webpage when I view inspect element) :

```
var g_rgAppContextData = {"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","icon":"http:\/\/cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg","link":"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/730"}};

fnInitItemDisplay = function() {
    UserYou.LoadContexts( g_rgAppContextData );
    BuildHover( 'economy_item_55a8de8719556',  {"id":"2871922729","owner":"76561198082527859","classid":"310777393","instanceid":"0","icon_url":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpopujwezhh3szdYz9D4uO6nYeDg7mmNe3UkD8GsMEo3erDp9St31K3_0JsZTqlLI-SdA5oZwuDqQW2lLrpm9bi6_KhRAkC","icon_url_large":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpopujwezhh3szdYz9D4uO6nYeDg8j4MqnWkyUD7pN0jL2WrYis31e2-UtkZD-gIIeVdFVoaVHX_Fnox7281sK06cnP1zI97bNcM7TE","icon_drag_url":"","name":"P250 | Metallic DDPAT","market_hash_name":"P250 | Metallic DDPAT (Factory New)","market_name":"P250 | Metallic DDPAT (Factory New)","name_color":"D2D2D2","background_color":"","type":"Industrial Grade Pistol","tradable":1,"marketable":1,"commodity":0,"market_tradable_restriction":"7","descriptions":[{"type":"html","value":"Exterior: Factory New"},{"type":"html","value":" "},{"type":"html","value":"A low-recoil firearm with a high rate of fire, the P250 is a relatively inexpensive choice against armored opponents. It has been painted using an urban Digital Disruptive Pattern (DDPAT) hydrographic over a metallic base coat."},{"type":"html","value":" "},{"type":"html","value":"The Train Collection","color":"9da1a9","app_data":{"def_index":"65535","is_itemset_name":1}},{"type":"html","value":" "}],"tags":[{"internal_name":"CSGO_Type_Pistol","name":"Pistol","category":"Type","category_name":"Type"},{"internal_name":"weapon_p250","name":"P250","category":"Weapon","category_name":"Weapon"},{"internal_name":"set_train","name":"The Train Collection","category":"ItemSet","category_name":"Collection"},{"internal_name":"normal","name":"Normal","category":"Quality","category_name":"Category"},{"internal_name":"Rarity_Uncommon_Weapon","name":"Industrial Grade","category":"Rarity","color":"5e98d9","category_name":"Quality"},{"internal_name":"WearCategory0","name":"Factory New","category":"Exterior","category_name":"Exterior"}],"pos":1,"appid":"730","contextid":"2"} );
    $('economy_item_55a8de8719556').show();
}

fnInitItemDisplay();
```

I am unsure how to do this.  I have tied `GetElementByID` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: "market_hash_name":"P250 | Metallic DDPAT (Factory New)"

Comment: When you say you have tried "GetElementByID" what do you mean? In C#? GetElementByID of what class?

Comment: I guess my question is, the text above is clearly a portion of the text of the entire webpage. Do you already have something to cull from the entire html page down to the `<script>` tag that contains this text?

Comment: @Mohamed4ch Yeah, he just never mentioned he was using a WebBrowser control anywhere...